# using watir for a facebook app

Tags: ruby, facebook, webdriver, watir

recently I'm using watir/ruby to publish on facebook automatically. In simple words I managed to write a sentence in the text field, but I can't click on the button "Publish".
I tried in different ways:

- browser.link(:value => '1').click
- browser.button(:value => "Publish").click
- browser.li(:xpath, '//INPUT[@type="submit"]').click
- browser.link(:href =>'javascript:doSubmit()').click
- browser.a(:text =>"Publish").click

but I get the error messages: unable to locate element, or element not visible.

I also tried to write:

- browser.button(:value => '1').exists?

but I got the answer "false". Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: Use the API. Scraping Facebook is not allowed

Comment: @WizKid.  This comes up a lot.  You should post this as an answer with a link to the FB TOS.

Comment: @orde: Unfortunately when i do I get downvoted because I don't answer the question. The scraping policy can be found at https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: @WizKid.  Too bad.  Because the TOS is clear: "You will not engage in Automated Data Collection without Facebook's express written permission."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is tons of Javascript on the page.
You should wait until your element appears.

Use corresponding functions [here](http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/)

Example:

```
browser.button(:value => "Publish").wait_until_present.click
```

Comment: I didn't know about the scraping_tos_terms on facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, posting information is not scraping information. I've definitely automated tests for Facebook with a test user account, which was absolutely in line with the TOS.

Is this an element that is showing up in a pop up window? If so you need to do something like: `browser.windows.last.use { browser.a(text: 'Publish').click }`

Comment: Yes, exactly. "Publish" is a button that appears when I start to write something in the textbox. I'm going to try the function you suggested me...  Thanks

Comment: I just tried and it didn't work. I got the same message: in 'assert exist': unable to locate element using {:text=>"Pubblica", :tag_name=>"a"}(Watir:: UnknownObjectException)

Comment: But the button exist because I can see it and I can click it manually... I just need to recognize it from my app... :-(